# Redirect all Browser Traffic to a Single Web Page

Tags: internet, browser, redirection

Simply put, I want to make a Windows 8.1 machine redirect all traffic to a page I specify. For instance, if I use Google Chrome, and type in any URL, I want the user to end up on, for example, imgur.com.  How would one go about accomplishing this?

I would like a browser androgynous answer if possible. Also, I do not have access to the network (router, LAN hub, etc.) controllers, just the client machine.

Comment: [Here is a similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/304156/how-to-reroute-all-traffic-using-hosts-file). If you can setup a DNS server, you can point the machine at that DNS, which reroutes everything, but it sounds like that's probably not an option.

Answer (score 1):

It's more of a networking thing so without access to the network configuration I'd say you should look at some parental control software. You'd just black list everything and set the warning redirect page to the site you want, not black listed of course.